# Java regex to split by comma but ignore comma inside comments

Tags: java

I need regex to split the string by Comma(,) but ignore the comma in commented part
I tried a lot after changing your regex.It was not succesful
eg.

```
Command=RTRV-EQPT, Completion Code= DENY, Error Code= II:AC, Problem Description=  /* Input Inva,lid *******ACcess =iden:tifier */, Comment=null,
```

Comment: How can you differentiate between comment/non-comment? Enclosed by `/`?

Comment: lookahead / lookbehind assertions will probably do the trick

Comment: Replace the comments with double-quotes (i.e. making a proper CSV) and use a proper CSV parser.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel: [here's an easy-to-use parser](http://pwm.googlecode.com/svn-history/r351/trunk/pwm/servlet/src/password/pwm/util/csv/CsvReader.java)

Answer (score 1):

for your particular case, why not removing the comment first and then split, it may simplify your problem.

```
txt.replace("/*reg to match the comment here */", " ").split(',');
```

Comment: regex to match comment `//.*|(\"(?:\\\\[^\"]|\\\\\"|.)*?\")|(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/`

Comment: Plus one for having a go at such RE, but is this one accurate?
What's the comment "grammar"? How are comments characters encoded (escaped? quoted?)
in an actual value? Consider {{ABC="/* this is a value */, DEF=XYZ}}.
The "grammar" for the comments appears to be simply "anything enclosed by /*...*/",
with the additional assumption that no comment characters appear in quoted value strings,
so double dash and special handling of double quotes seems a bit over the top.
The parser approach mentioned by others sounds OK.