# Splitting a string using delimiters-Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string and I would like to split the values seperately.

For instance, I would like to split the following string:

```
            Test1 Avg. running Time: 66,3 [ms], (Ref: 424.0) ===> Well done, It is 80% faster
```

I would want 66,3[ms] seperately and the Ref value seperately.

It would be helpful if any of you could suggest me which will eb the best way to do this.

Should I use a delimiter(:)? But in this case, I receive the output as

```
            66,3 [ms], (Ref: 424.0) ===> Well done, It is 80% faster
```

Or should I use a 'regex'?

Answer (score 1):

For this case you cas use `.split(", ");` because ',' have a blank after except in number.

Have also a look in *[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736524/java-regex-to-split-by-comma-but-ignore-comma-inside-comments/11737057#11737057)* for parser ready made.

Comment: If we split with `", "` the result is: `Test1 Avg. running Time: 66,3 [ms]`, `(Ref: 424.0) ===> Well done` and `It is 80% faster`. This requires a little more work to do to get values!

Comment: So you can use `str.substring(str.index(":") + 1, str.index("[")).trim()`, in the first split, and `str.substring(str.index(":") +1, str.index(")")).trim()`, in the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` function...

`String s = "66,3 [ms], (Ref: 424.0) ===> Well done, It is 80% faster";`

`String[] arr = s.split(", ");`

Answer (score 0):

use this way

```
public class JavaStringSplitExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String str = "one-two-three";
        String[] temp;

        String delimiter = "-";

        temp = str.split(delimiter);

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            System.out.println(temp[i]);

        /*
         * NOTE : Some special characters need to be escaped while providing
         * them as delimiters like "." and "|".
         */

        System.out.println("");
        str = "one.two.three";
        delimiter = "\\.";
        temp = str.split(delimiter);
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            System.out.println(temp[i]);

        /*
         * Using second argument in the String.split() method, we can control
         * the maximum number of substrings generated by splitting a string.
         */

        System.out.println("");
        temp = str.split(delimiter, 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            System.out.println(temp[i]);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
    String test = "Test1 Avg. running Time: 66,3 [ms], (Ref: 424.0) ===> Well done, It is 80% faster"; 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+[.,]?\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    m.find();
    String avgRunningTime = m.group(1);
    m.find();
    String ref = m.group(1);
    System.out.println("avgRunningTime: "+avgRunningTime+", ref: "+ref);
```

This would print:

```
    avgRunningTime: 66,3, ref: 424.0
```

You will naturally want to add some error checking (e.g. check if `m.find()` returns `true`).